# How do I parse a page using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse the URL shown in the `doc` variable below.  My issue is with the `job` variable.  When I return it, it returns every job title on the page instead of that specific job title for the given review.  Does anyone have advice how to return the specific job title I'm referring to?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Perform a google search
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Microsoft-Reviews-E1651.htm'))

reviews = []


current_review = Hash.new

doc.css('.employerReview').each do |item|
    pro = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(1) .notranslate').text
    con = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(2) .notranslate').text
    job = item.parent.css('.review-microdata-heading .i-occ').text
    puts job
    advice = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(3) .notranslate').text

    current_review = {'pro' => pro, 'con' => con, 'advice' => advice}

    reviews << current_review
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `item.parent` is `#MainCol` in each case, in other words the entire column.

Changing `item.parent.css` to `item.css` should solve your problem.